# Unicode alphanumeric character range

Tags: unicode

I'm looking at the [IsCharAlphaNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647483%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) Windows API function. As it only takes a single TCHAR, it obviously can't make any decisions about surrogate pairs for UTF16 content. Does that mean that there are no alphanumeric characters that are surrogate pairs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Characters outside the BMP can be letters. (Michael Kaplan recently [discussed a bug in the classification of the character U+1F48C](http://www.siao2.com/2011/11/18/10238393.aspx).) But `IsCharAlphaNumeric` cannot see characters outside the BMP (for the reasons you noted), so you cannot obtain classification information for them that way.

<strike>If you have a surrogate pair, call `GetStringType` with `cchSrc = 2` and check for `C1_ALPHA` and `C1_DIGIT`.</strike>

**Edit**: The second half of this answer is incorrect [`GetStringType` does not support surrogate pairs](http://www.siao2.com/2011/11/21/10239128.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can determine yourself by looking at the [Unicode plane assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane) what you are missing by not being able to inspect non-BMP codepoints.

For example, you won't be able to identify imperial Aramaic characters as alphanumeric. Shame.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean that there are no alphanumeric characters that are surrogate pairs?

No, there are supplementary code-points that are in the letter group.

[Comparing a char to a code-point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029897/comparing-a-char-to-a-code-point/1030066#1030066)

> For example, `Character.isLetter('\uD840')` returns `false`, even though this specific value if followed by any low-surrogate value in a string would represent a letter.