# How to iterate Punjabi, Arabic Language in Java?

Tags: java, arabic-support

If we want to iterate through the characters of a string in Java
we can do like this

```
String s = "... ahmad sardar awais ,.l. dausaj";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            System.out.println( c );
         }
```

But my problem is that I have punjabi or Arabic language in my Arraylist then how to iterate and get single character ?

My String in ArrayList is `مجھے اچھا لڑکا ہوں`

Now I want this String Split in single character, how to do this ?

Comment: What's the behaviour when you split Punjabi/Arabic text? Doesn't it work as expected?

Comment: It cannot traverse character by character, whole word traversed

Comment: You might need codepoints for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527856/how-can-i-iterate-through-the-unicode-codepoints-of-a-java-string or http://stackoverflow.com/a/1031647/3848666